# Trying to parse a beautifulsoap scrape for a specific row but I think it doesn't parse according to class or rowid -- ex. I want text for rowid=2

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get info (text) for rowid=2 (this should have narrowed the content significantly but I keep getting text for all requested td(s) or tr(s). Can you kindly help with this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers_param = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
bist = requests.get("https://www.borsaistanbul.com/tr/endeks", headers=headers_param)
# print(bist.content)
jobs = bist.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(jobs,"html.parser")
all_jobs = soup.find_all("tr",{"rowid":"2"})
# for job in all_jobs:
# print(job)
all_jobs = soup.find_all("tr")
for data in all_jobs:
   print(data.text)
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. What is "info-text" and are you aware that there are multiple `tr` with that attribute?

Comment: By info I meant the text in tr with rowid=2 (or 3 etc.). Yes, I am aware of multiple tr(s) which I am trying to eliminate and get a tr with class"same-in-all" but rowid=2 (or 3 etc.)

Comment: And what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still use `.text` but on a second selection for `all_jobs`, so I could not see a general issue.

May clean up your code and also may use `.get_text()` or `.stripped_strings` to get a better result:

```
all_jobs = soup.find_all("tr",{"rowid":"2"})
for data in all_jobs: 
    print(data.get_text(',', strip=True))
```

---

```
all_jobs = soup.find_all("tr",{"rowid":"2"})
for data in all_jobs: 
    print(','.join(data.stripped_strings))
```

---

```
BIST 100,XU100,3.11.2023,7.705,99,0,55,7.721,18,7.581,57,TL,2,55,39,88,01.01.1986,0,01
BIST-KYD DİBS 91 GUN,TD91G,3.11.2023,3.298,44448,-0,89,3.330,14214,3.298,44448,TL,-1,00,9,03,31.12.2001,100
BIST ALTIN,ATKMP,3.11.2023,4.575,76454,-0,52,4.655,55300,4.528,85721,TL,-0,25,9,64,31.12.2004,1000
BIST 100 RK %10 (TOPLAM GETIRI),RK100T10,3.11.2023,2.106,8786,0,19,2.106,8786,2.106,8786,TL,0,78,18,33,31.12.2003,100,0000
TURK LIRASI GECELIK REFERANS FAIZ ORANI,TLREF,3.11.2023,34,1301,-0,11,34,1301,34,1301,TL,1,79,232,51,28.12.2018,0,00
TURK LIRASI GECELIK KATILIM REFERANS GETIRI ORANI,TLREFK,3.11.2023,33,4117,0,13,33,4117,33,4117,TL,0,80,243,73,22.06.2022,0,00
```

Comment: Kindly note that I am at crawling stages with Python!

Comment: <tr class="bolder-and-larger header2" rowid="2" style="background-color: white; border: 0px; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-collapse: unset">

Comment: This is the tag coglomeration: I want something like: BIST 100, 3.11.2023, 7705,99, 0,55, 7721.18 etc. Just that row with rowid=2

Comment: code like below did not work:                                                                                    
all_jobs = soup.find_all("tr",{"rowid":"2"})

Comment: Without a clear description of the problem and the expectations, it is difficult to help, all the information given so far in the comments seems to be contradictory. Even a statement like the code does not work is unfortunately only of limited help. If you just want to get the first occurring line with the `rowid="2"` use `find()` instead of `find_all()`. If it is only about getting the first occurring line with the `rowid="2"` use `find()` instead of `find_all()`. -> `soup.find("tr",{"rowid":"2"}).get_text(',', strip=True)`

Comment: That 'diddn't work' section was given to me by my instructor. I wasn't commenting on your code - so, sorry for that - I'll check your code and will let you know. Thank you for your help till now...

Comment: YESSSSS, IT WORKED...I CAN'T TELL YOU HOW HAPPY I AM. THANK YOU SO MUCH. CORDIAL SALUTATIONS!!! - serhat

Comment: The code for someone else who may need it: all_veri = soup.find("tr",{"rowid":"2"})
for data in all_veri: 
    print(data.get_text(',', strip=True))